# C# excel close process still left

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, process

I am open and close an excel book fro mC# like this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook  = null;

try
{

    excelWorkbook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(MyFile,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                true, false, 0, true, false, false);

    .....
    ....
    ....

    excelWorkbook.Save();
    excelWorkbook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    oXL.Quit();
    excelWorkbook = null;
    oXL = null;

}
catch { }
```

But there is stil lan EXCEL.EXE process left running in the task list, why ?
how do I "kill" everything about excel when I am done ?
Is it not enough with ".Quit()" and put the reference to null ?

or is there some magic reference left in the C# heap somewhere that have not been 
dereferenced ?

/Stefan

Comment: Duplicate question. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685159/unable-to-diligently-close-the-excel-process-running-in-memory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685159/unable-to-diligently-close-the-excel-process-running-in-memory  might be helpful for you

Comment: Please stop turning question titles into a string of meaningless tags, tags belong into the tags section, the question title should be an actual question which describes the problem. (I am especially referring to some of your other questions, as this one even does make sense to some minro degree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
oXL.quit()
```

// Note, oXL still points to excel

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL)
oXL = Nothing
```